# Calculating the coupon code discount in django Template

Tags: javascript, html, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Here im trying to calculate the coupon discount Here my Coupon Code is FREE20 That means 20% Discount

This is my output ...

`Items : ₹2699.0`
`Tax  : ₹5`
`Coupon Code Applied : 20%`
`Delivery Charge : ₹10`
`Total Amount : ₹2714`

But I want to get the 20 % discount...I'm trying to solve this way

Here item amount is 2699 And 20% of 2699 = 539

item amount + tax + deliver charge = 2699+5+10 = 2714

So 2714 - 539 = 2175

I think this is Correct

But in this code coupon code discount is not working properly

Model

```
class CouponCode(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    discount = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self) :
        return self.code
```

HTML

```
<h2>Cart totals</h2>
<ul class="mb-20 shadow-sm p-3 mb-5  rounded">
   <li>Items <span>₹{{cart_total_amount}}</span></li>
   <li>Tax <span>₹{{tax}}</span></li>
   {% if valid_coupon %}
   <li>Coupon Code Applied <span>{{coupon.discount}}%</span></li>
   {% endif %}
   {% if cart_total_amount > 3000 %}
   <li>Delivery Charge <span>Free</span></li>
   <li>Total Amount <span>₹{{cart_total_amount|add:tax}}</span></li>
   {% else %}
   <li>Delivery Charge <span>₹10</span></li>
   <li class="fw-bold">Total Amount <span>₹{{cart_total_amount|add:tax|add:10}}</span></li>
   {% endif %}
</ul>
```

View

```
def cart_detail(request):
    cart = request.session.get('cart')
    tax = sum(i.get('tax', 0) for i in cart.values() if i)

    coupon = None
    valid_coupon = None
    invalid_coupon = None

    if request.method =='GET':
        coupon_code = request.GET.get('coupon_code')
        if coupon_code:
            try:
                coupon = CouponCode.objects.get(code=coupon_code)
                valid_coupon = "Are Applicable on Current Product"
            except:
                invalid_coupon = "Invalid Coupon code"


    context = {
        'tax' : tax,
        'coupon' : coupon,
        'valid_coupon' : valid_coupon,
        'invalid_coupon' : invalid_coupon,


    }
    return render(request, 'cart/cart.html', context)
```

Script Tag

```
<script>
    var item_amounts = '{{ cart_total_amount }}';
    var tax = '{{ tax }}';
    var total = item_amounts + tax;

    var coupon_discount = '{{coupon.discount}}'
    console.log(coupon_discount)
    if(coupon_discount){
        if(item_amounts < 3000){
            cal_discount = item_amounts - (item_amounts + coupon_discount / 100) + total + 10
            document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "₹" + " " + cal_discount.toFixed()
        }
        else{
            cal_discount = item_amounts - (item_amounts + coupon_discount / 100) + total 
            document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "₹" + " " + cal_discount.toFixed()
        }
    }


</script>
```

Anyone, please help me to solve this

I want to get the 20% offer of total amount